# can a python function call a global function with the same name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, namespaces, python-internals

Can I call a global function from a function that has the same name?

For example:

```
def sorted(services):
    return {sorted}(services, key=lambda s: s.sortkey())
```

By `{sorted}` I mean the global sorted function.
Is there a way to do this?
I then want to call my function with the module name:  `service.sorted(services)`

I want to use the same name, because it does the same thing as the global function, except that it adds a default argument.

Comment: Can you just write the code you would want to be able to write, run it, and if it fails tell us what the error message is?

Comment: Of course you can access `__builtins__.sorted`, but what you're doing sounds like a bad plan.

Comment: Just don't name your function the same as a built-in. Problem solved.

Comment: If that function is not within a class, it is itself a global. If it is within a class, calling `sorted` instead of `self.sorted` or `cls.sorted` would do the job already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python's name-resolution scheme which sometimes is referred to as `LEGB` rule, implies that when you use an unqualified name inside a function, Python searches up to four scopes— **First** the local (L) scope, then the local scopes of any enclosing (E) `def`s and `lambda`s, then the global (G) scope, and finally the built-in (B) scope. (Note that it will stops the search as soon as it finds a match)

So when you use `sorted` inside the functions interpreter considers it as a **Global** name (your function name) so you will have a recursion function. if you want to access to built-in `sorted` you need to specify that for Python . by `__builtin__` module (**in Python-2.x** ) and [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) in Python-3.x (This module provides direct access to all ‘built-in’ identifiers of Python)

---

python 2 :

```
import __builtin__
def sorted(services):
    return __builtin__.sorted(services, key=lambda s: s.sortkey())
```

python 3 :

```
import builtins
def sorted(services):
    return builtins.sorted(services, key=lambda s: s.sortkey())
```

Comment: You should add proper attribution when using content from external sources: http://users.atw.hu/learningpython/lpython2-chp-13-sect-1.html

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary yes , you're right , but as i read this content about some month ago and didn't remember it well i just copied the fist part  and as i add some extra words in it , i though that there is no need to give the source . i other word i mean that i knew the main notion , there is no need to add reference , but any way i think you're right , thanks for reminding

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered

Comment: builtins is exactly what I was looking for.  Whether this is a bad idea or not I will find out from experience.

Answer (score 5):

Store the original function reference before define a new function with the same name.

```
original_sorted = sorted

def sorted(services):
    return original_sorted(services, key=lambda s: s.sortkey())
```

For, builtin functions like [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted), you can access the function using [`__builtin__` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html) (In Python 3.x, [`builtins` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html)):

```
import __builtin__

def sorted(services):
    return __builtin__.sorted(services, key=lambda s: s.sortkey())
```

But, both which shadow builtin function is not recommended. Choose other name if possible.

Comment: original_sorted doesn't work for me.  I am doing this inside a module in Python 3.x.  I get this error:  AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'sorted'

Comment: @user13097, Could you provide the source your run? What about `__builtin__` / `builtins` approache?

Comment: @user13097, See the demo that use `original_sorted`: http://asciinema.org/a/15036